# Implement video filtering and save filtered video

Tags: android, video, filter

How can i implement video filter like Instagram in android studio? I've seen a lot of topics here it didn't really help me. I don't want to use FFMPEG, first of all its complicated and uses a lot of CPU load.

Answer (score 1):

Just make filtering on GPU. Look through [gpuimage](https://github.com/cats-oss/android-gpuimage) library. It incorporates plenty varied filters, you can create own if you want as well. So, as we talk about video, of cource be ready to implement per-frame processing.

Comment: I will try this out